# How do you mount a specific btrfs subvolume?

Tags: mount, fstab, btrfs

Suppose I start with a non-btrfs system and then add a secondary drive that I format as btrfs. How would I mount /var/log on a subvolume of the new drive instead of on the original drive? Is this even possible?

I've created the fs and the subvolume 'log' on it, but no syntax I try gets it to mount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that you just have to specify the id of the subvolume. To find it, do

```
# btrfs subvolume list <path to btrfs drive/fs>
```

For fstab, the line will be very similar to the line for the btrfs drive in general, but with the **subvolid** option set. Mine looks like this since I'm using LVM:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-vmdrive /mnt/vmdrive   btrfs    defaults 0 0
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-vmdrive /var/log       btrfs    defaults,compress=lzo,commit=120,subvolid=408 0       0
```

Your subvolid will probably be different.

Also, watch out for permission. As with any mount, you might need to set the uid/gid or umask, especially for something like /var/log.